# Why was my flag declined yet the post was closed for the reason I flagged?

Tags: bug, flagging

So I flagged [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38709/why-dont-pilots-or-passengers-for-that-matter-yet-seem-to-really-like-auto) as being opinion based and the flag got declined, yet the question is currently [on hold] for being opinion based.

Has something gone wrong with the system?

Declined flag...
[image: Flag declined]

Question Closed...
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [the link to a meta.SO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284872/6650102) given by Aurora0001 in the comments, and the fact that [the review](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/23980) shows that nobody in the queue agreed with you, the system has "declined" automatically this flag.

The question then got closed through a second [queue](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/23993)

Answer (score -6):

Four possible reasons.

1. Declined by mistake. It happens.
2. A mod has a vendetta against you. It also happens. Often.
3. Some mods think flagging for close reasons should not be done and blanket decline. This is wrong.

But from the looks of it,

4. it timed out, because the question was closed by user votes, making your pending flag pointless. The system, for whatever reason, marks these as declined, instead of simply unflagging or some other option.

If you mouse over the time stamp on your declined flag, and compare it to the close time stamp of the question, they should overlap.

Edit: since it wasn't a timed out flag, then:

5. The mod that saw the flag simply didn't agree with the close reason. Notice no mod had casted a close vote on it. The problem is that votes and flags are opinion, and not everyone holds the same opinion on any given question.

Comment: There was 10 hours 40 minutes between my flag and the question being closed.

Comment: Hello cde, welcome to Aviation.SE. I don't see where your second point comes from: `A mod has a vendetta against you. It also happens. Often.` I'd like to think that is not the case.  I am contributing to this website since the first day and I have never observed such behaviour by any of our moderators. Your statement comes across as quite offensive. Do you have any evidence to back up your claim?

Comment: I agree with @DeltaLima. The mods on this site are great, and we don't see that kind of thing.  Perhaps you have run across that on other sites but I'd be shocked to hear that you have experienced anything like that on Aviation.SE!

Comment: *A mod has a vendetta against you. It also happens. Often* Nope. -1 for fabrication.

Comment: If only you can see the email history revolving around a few mods that were forcibly removed.

Comment: A few (rogue) mods happens. Vendettas *might* happen. But "Often". I think not. I also think a bit offensive to the many people who give their time for free!

Comment: 'Recommend closure' flags like this are never sent to the moderator flag queue; they go directly to the Close Votes queue where users vote to close or leave open. It's unlikely a moderator was ever involved—the flag is simply declined if the review result is 'Leave Open' from three users without anyone agreeing with the flag.